# Binding DataTable to DataGrid C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

New to MVVM and struggling to figure out where I went wrong when attempting to bind a dynamically generated DataTable with a DataGrid. I've found some solutions and attempted to make adjustments to my implementation based on previous responses:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid" Margin="5,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding dataTable, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header1" Binding="{Binding Column1Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header2" Binding="{Binding Column2Name}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:Presenter/>
</DataGrid.DataContext>
```

XAML CS:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
Grid.DataContext = dataTable.DefaultView;
//I don't believe I should be using System.Data in View?
```

ViewModel

.Presenter:

```
public class Presenter : ObservableObject {
private DataTable _dataTable;


public DataTable dataTable
    {
        get { return _dataTable; }
        set
        {
            _dataTable = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Grid");
        }
    }

private void ParseData()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ID)) return;
        dataTable = DataParser.ParseURL(ID);
    }
}
```

.ObservableObject

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I know the data from the model is returning correctly, and when I'm in debugger the RaisePropertyChangedEvent is firing, but the view is not being updated.

Comment: Top tip: if you're using C#6 or above, you can use `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));` instead of creating a variable and checking for `null` :)

Comment: First rename the dataTable to DataTable no the issue just annoying. Second for the name of the property use "DataTable"  not "Grid" or use a proper implementation for notification. You can also use the nameof(DataGrid) in c# 6

Comment: Implemented both of these suggestions; Still haven't gotten it to work, but with the changes I've made here I'm hoping that prior articles might get me up and going.

Answer (score 2):

You're raising the wrong `PropertyName` (which appears to be the name of your `Grid` in the XAML.

Raise the name `"dataTable"` when calling your `RaisePropertyChanged` method.

Like so:

```
public DataTable dataTable
{
    get { return _dataTable; }
    set
    {
        _dataTable = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("dataTable");
    }
}
```

---

A few other things you can do are:

- Use `[CallerMemberName]` attribute before the `propertyName` parameter. This will save you having to provide it, as it detects what property is calling it (C#5 and above) - e.g.: `protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent([CallerMemberName] string propertyName)`
- Use `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));` in your `RaisePropertyChanged` method. This saves you having to create a variable and check for `null` (C#6 and above)
- Rename your `dataTable` property to `DataTable` - it creates better clarity as to what are properties and what are fields, and it's a commonplace thing to do in C#

---

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the name to "dataTable" and it is still not working. I'm also going to refactor based on your feedback. I have concerns that my binding in the XAML headers is not correct, could that be why its not pulling in the correct information?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are setting the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` to the `DataView` of the `DataTable` like this:

```
Grid.DataContext = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

...you should bind directly to the `DataContext`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid" Margin="5,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Center">
...
```

If you want to bind to your `dataTable` property, you should set the `DataContext` to an instance of your `Presenter` class:

```
var p = new Presenter();
Grid.DataContext = p;
```

---

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid" Margin="5,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding dataTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

Then you can set the `dataTable` property of the `Presenter` object to a new `DataTable`:

```
p.dataTable = new DataTable();
```

You still need to modify your property as suggested by @Geoff James:

```
public DataTable dataTable
{
    get { return _dataTable; }
    set
    {
        _dataTable = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("dataTable");
    }
}
```